# Laravel 5 Ajax Post route

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, jquery-ui-sortable

This is my first attempt to use ajax to Post instead of Get. I get a 200 response as if it were working but the function in the controller is never being run.

I used this same concept in my ajax Get requests and they work fine but the Post is not working as expected and sortable('serialize') creates a Post variable so I need to use Post.

The alert in the success: function always runs as if it were successful but the controller function is never hit (I have it making a simple database change just to verify if it is running).

Ajax:

```
$(function() {
  $('[id^="sortable_"]').sortable(
    {
        connectWith: '.sortable-line-item-list-5',    
        update : function (event, ui) 
        { 
        var items = $(this).sortable('serialize');  
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '/api/sort_order_item',
                data: {
                    'items': items,
                },
                success: function()
                {
                    alert('looks like it is working...');
                },
            });
        }
    });
    $( '[id^="sortable_"]' ).disableSelection();
});
```

Route:

```
Route::post('api/sort_order_item', ['as' => 'api/sort_order_item', 'uses' =>'ApiController@SortOrderItem']);
```

Controller:

```
public function SortOrderItem()
{
    $this_item = \pmms\Checklist_template_line_item::findOrFail(20);
    $this_item->list_position = 1;
    $this_item->save(); 
}
```

Comment: If the request is not hitting the method then you should not get a `200` status code. It's hitting the method, make sure by `dd(app('request')->all())` in the method and check the network tab in your browser. Also you didn't use `return` keyword and didn't send a response back.

Comment: I tired both of those things - the dd() is never hit in the method. The return keyword doesn't return anything either. I looked at the network tab in Chrome it shows a 200 response but coming from localhost/home, not the api/sort_order_item which returns a 302 just before it.

Comment: Then there is a redirect for `auth` like things.

Comment: I have:
Route::controllers([
 'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
 'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
Is that what is redirecting? If so, how do I modify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is csrf_token,
Put this line in your blade page head section:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

then, update your ajax code like this :

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/api/sort_order_item',
            data: {
                'items': items,
                '_token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
            },
            success: function()
            {
                alert('looks like it is working...');
            },
        });
```

Let me know if it helps you

Comment: Yes!!! That was it, the csrf token was failing and rerouting to the login screen by design.