# Problem passing AJAX data tot laravel controller

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

i'm relatively new to javascript and laravel.

I'm currently trying to make a JQVmap with different date range tabs. The problem i'm currently having is passing the dates from my date range picker plugin to my laravel controller.

**I have included the meta tag:**

```
  <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

**Javascript code:**

```
var startRange = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
var endRange = end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');


  $.ajaxSetup({
headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
}
});
var start = startRange;
 var end = endRange;




  $.ajax({
      url: "{{ route('home.ajax') }}",
      method: "POST",
      data:{start:start, end:end},

      succes: function(data){
          alert(data.success);
      }
  });
```

**Controller**

```
public function ajax(Request $request){

        $input = $request->all();
        \Log::info($input);

        return response()->json(['success'=>'Got Simple Ajax Request.']);
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('ajax/dates', 'HomeController@ajax')->name('home.ajax')->middleware('guest');
```

**When visiting ajax/dates, i get the following:**

Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

**When i look in my console, it says:**

jquery.min.js:2 GET http://adminpanel.test/home 404 (Not Found)

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: try  `url: "/ajax/dates",`

Comment: Already tried that, doesn't work

Comment: check your route list using `php artisan route:list` then if you have url like this you can use it check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36377720/laravel-5-ajax-post-route

Comment: What other routes you have in route file?

Comment: Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::post('/ajax/dates', 'HomeController@ajax')->name('home.ajax')->middleware('guest');
Auth::routes();

Comment: Fixed it with protected $except = [
        'ajax/dates',
    ];
} in VerifyCsrfToken.php